# Search in redis for keys not matching given pattern

Tags: database, search, data-structures, redis

The goal is to design a queue with the some values say A. but I have to pick a value from the queue only if incoming value D doesn't matches with B & C.

The relation between A, B and C can be think of as a tabular data.

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        A         |        B         |        C         |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 12312            | 123123           | 2323             |
| <some int value> | <some int value> | <some int value> |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I have an incoming value D.

Now I have to simply select value A from the row where value of D is not equal to either B or C.

Please note neither of A, B, C are known to in advance. These will be populated by a separate process either in db or redis. The only value I know is D  and I have to find the value of A for the first row I find where values B and C are not matching with D.

This is very simple to do if i do this on a relational DB i.e sample query would be

```
Select A from table where B != D and C != D LIMIT 1
```

But I am not sure how I can do this using key-value store like redis?

## Try 1

The most basic idea will be to maintain a list in redis in following format

```
somekey: ['a1:b1:c1', 'a2:b2:c2', 'a3:b3:c3', ...]
```

then I could simply run `lrange somekey 0 -1` and then iterate over every elment, split on `:` untill I find an element where `b` and `c` both are not equal to `D`.

But This approach is very expensive, as I have to iterate over entire every list for every value of D.

## Try 2

Another approach I have tried to create redis keys in the following format

```
+------------------+-----------------------------+
|       Key        |            Value            |
+------------------+-----------------------------+
| prefix_<B1>_<C1> | [<A11>, <A12>, <A13>, ....] |
| prefix_<B2>_<C2> | [<A21>, <A22>, <A23>, ....] |
+------------------+-----------------------------+
```

The problem with this approach is that redis doesn't support the searching for keys `not matching a pattern`.

So I have to first get all keys then, do a regex search on application level.

Then once I find a key, i just pop first value from the list at that key.

My preferred approach is to do it using redis, but other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: You might want to consider a more efficient way based on RediSearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you store values in the following format:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| key          | value           |
+--------------+-----------------+
| a1:b1:c1     | any value       |
+--------------+-----------------+
| a2:b2:c2     | any value       |
+--------------+-----------------+
| a3:b3:c3     | any value       |
+--------------+-----------------+
| a4:b4:c4     | any value       |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

For any value `d` you want all the keys that does not contain d:d as suffix such as `whatever:d:d`, here is the following regex that will return all the keys that does not `d:d` in suffix.

```
KEYS *[^d:d]
```

suppose values of `d` is `123` then the pattern will be: `*[^123:123]`.

Here are some cases which I've tested in my console:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set 123:456:789 one
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set 123:456:780 two
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set 123:456:787 two
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set 123:455:787 two
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set aaa:bbb:ccc abc
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set aaa:ddd:ddd abc
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "123:456:789"
2) "123:456:787"
3) "123:455:787"
4) "aaa:ddd:ddd"
5) "aaa:bbb:ccc"
6) "123:456:780"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys aaa:*[^ddd:ddd]
1) "aaa:bbb:ccc"
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *[^ddd:ddd]
1) "123:456:789"
2) "123:456:787"
3) "123:455:787"
4) "aaa:bbb:ccc"
5) "123:456:780"
```

see command `keys *[^ddd:ddd]` returning all the keys which does not matched with our expected key.

```
1) "123:456:789"
2) "123:456:787"
3) "123:455:787"
4) "aaa:bbb:ccc"
5) "123:456:780"
```

for more check this link: [REDIS KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys)

You can also use [REDIS SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command to fetch not matching keys:

```
scan 0 MATCH *[^d:d] count 1000
```

Comment: neither of A, B, C are known to in advance. These will be populated by a separate process either in db or redis. The only value I know is D  and I have to find the value of A for the first row I find where values B and C are not matching with D.

Comment: @SushilSingh does it meet your requirement?

Comment: @thanks ruhul. I thought redis can only accept wildcard characters and not a complete regex.